# Mackbook Pro Retina and health?

Tags: macbook-pro

I just changed from a normal macbook pro to the gorgeous mbp retina display, I have been using it 3 days and Im starting with headaches and eye pain!
I really dont know wats happening, I mean the display is beautiful but although I use it in the minor bright Im still having eye and head issues!

If anyone can help me with an experience or something it would be really nice.

Comment: Actually a persona note, go see a eye doctor (optometrist) to find out if you need a prescription. Typical headaches and eye pain come from you trying to focus your eyes (it is the eye muscle cramp).

Answer (score 3):

Because objects are smaller a sharper your eyes are trying to focus on that.

The constant focusing strains your eye muscles, resulting in eye pain and headache.

I would see a optometrist and get a prescription, or just buy a reading glasses at any store, starting a 0.5 strength to see it that helps (they cost around $5)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I need to see an optometrist so I dont get hurt when working because I spend around 5 hours a day in the mb, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem. I didn’t know if it was the Retina screen. Actually I searched and tried some many solutions. These are what I collected; I hope it could help most of MBP eye discomfort.

1. Maybe the fonts are too small, or the backlight too bright, try to adjust font and backlight brightness as the same as the former computer.
2. Go to the eye doctor and take some advices. Try to decrease the length of time in front of your MBP and balance it with breaks.
3. Check if the bluetooth that is giving you a terrible headache.
4. Install an eye protection app – F.lux. It can really help reduce eye strain and discomfort when I used a Windows PC. But it also has a Mav version.
5. Choose computer eyewear like Gunnar and T’amie Optics. They can filter the harmful lights.
6. Return your MBP to store. (This is what I did)

More:  If you work for 2 hours in front of a PC, you have 90% chance to get CVS. 
 Get to learn this source: [Everything you need to know about CVS](http://www.taimeopt.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-cvs/).

Hope you have adjusted to your MBP now.